# How to use New Relic RUM with HTML only sites?

Tags: newrelic

We are using New Relic to monitor our REST-API, which is working quite well.

The question is how to add RUM to a plain-HTML application, which is calling our REST-API and is not served by RoR or JSPs? 
I saw several examples how to use it with RoR or JSPs, where the Agents automatically adding the necessary lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The New Relic RUM beacon is unique for each request, so you need some kind of server side processing. So no, this is not possible.

Comment: Thx. Maybe we are to early for the world with sending plain-html, but I think this would be an awesome feature. ;)

Comment: Yeah, hehe. And properly not undoable, but 95 of the features in New Relic would not be used in this scenario.